# Find row with date, active cell in fixed column, and write timestamp

Tags: excel, vba

I want create a excel to record some times (enter to work, exit to dinner...). I tought the best way to do it is excel with vba code.

I put some bottons ([like in photo I upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbieF.png)) to record some important times, and I create a table with days in month and events to record.

But, the problem is in vba code. I'm very inexpert in excel vba and only get this code:

```
Sub time()

    ActiveCell.Value = Now

End Sub
```

In active cell, this code write timestamp.... But I want more advanced code. For example, I have button 'Enter to work', and I want when I press it:

- Excel find row refers to today date
- Find column 'Enter to work'
- And write timestamp (hour:minute:second) in this cell

I don't know how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's probably for the best you look up some tutorials and attempt some coding yourself. This is not a free coding service :) Just start with simple tasks and if you have any questions, feel free to use stackoverflow, but don't just come here and request somebody to do an entire project for you

Comment: It is not my intention that you make me entire project... I only want some help to develop this

Comment: hi, start to record a macro, see the code and change it to your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below. First you will get the last row of your date than just use a loop to cycle through and compare the date on the sheet with the `Now()` function that returns today's date. Then you can use the `offset` to write the time to next cell. You can assign the macro to the buttons on the spredsheet and will be triggered each time. I guess you can put another if statement to check if there are values in the cell before attempting to write just to avoid overriding data. Note the date format on the sheet should be `14/05/2019`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillInForm()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim LRow As Long
Dim dateFormatter As String
Dim xDate As Date

  Set WS = ActiveSheet
  dateFormatter = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy")
  xDate = CDate(dateFormatter)

    With WS
        LRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 5 To LRow
             If CDate(.Range("B" & i).value) = CDate(xDate) Then
                    If .Range("B" & i).Offset(0, 1).value = vbNullString Then
                        .Range("B" & i).Offset(0, 1).value = VBA.DateTime.Time
                    End If
             End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```